# Is Kashin Koji actually someone who has appeared in Naruto before?

Tags: boruto

So I've been reading the *Boruto* manga lately. There was this member of a secret organization Kara called Kashin Koji.

Many have speculated that he is

> Jiraiya

or his clone (or student/son, etc.)

They claim this because:

1. His appearance in front of Boruto and squad was with a toad summoning.
2. He knows how to make a Rasengan perfectly.

Does this theory have any credibility?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, there are coincidences that Kashin Koji and Jiraiya could be the same, but you also have to realize that Jiraiya died and there was no way he was surviving after the fight with Pain.

Pain finished him and that was the end of Jiraiya, now where the Rasengan and the toad summoning comes into place, it could be very possible that he might have been a relative of Jiraya, but as it looks, we won't find out until we get more information.

Comment: After reading it again, small comment I would make would be that maybe Kashin Koji saw the rasengan in the previous fight and maybe laerned it quickly. He does seem like a very skilled ninja so there is a possibility that could happen.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard those rumors too and to be honest, that seems like a plausible theory. But there are 2 counteracting facts for that theory. The first is that Jiraiya's body was lost into the ocean when pain destroyed his back with chakra rods; so its almost impossible for anyone to have acquired his DNA, except maybe they got it long before he died (or how Kabuto wanted to get his DNA).

The second fact is the way Kashin Koji's personality is displayed in the manga, unlike Jiraiya, If i were to describe his personality, Kashin Koji seems more like a self centered, "no nonsense" type of person who is serious minded and very calculating. That is very contrasting to the fun loving, super pervy and social Jiraiya that we all know.

Also, It seems very unlikely that Jiraiya had a son, but then again,  since Jiraiya was such a perv, it wont come as a surprise that the one and only ERO SENIN had some secret relationship and something along the lines resulted in Kashin being born.

Nevertheless, the theory that i feel could be the closest is that Kashin Koji could be a  student of Jiraiya Sensei. Since Jiraiya was able to teach Naruto the rasengan and summoning jutsu, it would make sense to hypothesize that he probably  taught other students too. The possibility that ERO SENIN had a couple more students aside Mnato, Nagato and his crew, and Naruto is not a far fetched idea. Lets not forget that after Jiraiya recieved the Great Gamamaru's vision of the future, he decided to go around, traveling and looking for the so called "child of prophecy". He might have had a couple other students during the years that he travelled around writing books.

PS: My answers are based of assumptions so there's a possibility that I could be really close, or completely wrong in the theory.

Answer (score 0):

In the last chapter of the manga, we actually get a hint that ties Kashin Koji to Konoha, which makes things even more interesting and complicated at the same time. What we know until now is that:

1. there is a certain physical resemblance between him and Jiraya (the hair, the age, the two strikes on their faces which are exactly on the same spot - under their eyes)
2. they use similar jutsus: fire-based techniques, Rasengan, toad summoning, sealing jutsu
3. while his partner had to wait outside the village since she couldn't go through the Yamanaka clan's barrier without being detected, Kashin Koji had no difficulty to enter the village. He said it himself that anyone who didn't have their chakra registered in Konoha's security system would not be able to enter without triggering the alarm.

So, IMO, that might be a hint that he is a former shinobi from Konohagakure. He also knows a lot about the village, which kind of makes me think that maybe he grew up there or something.

Of course, we can't conclude that based on this information he is Jiraiya, but it surely makes us wonder about his past, his connection to the Leaf and his identity.

Answer (score 0):

No he isnt, but he's a clon of the person you believed to be

> Jiraiya

[Koji Kashin](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Koji_Kashin)

Answer (score -2):

It can be Jiraiya, just like what happen to Ao's.

During the war, as you remember in the chapter, Kara is already in process.
They rescued Ao's because of his eye use byakugan, they fix him and revive his body.

Maybe Jiraiya was rescued too by Kara, and they fix his body as a totally cyborg or whatsoever. Because it seems when he use to get his frog out, the frog looks like something different. It looks like the frog was already developed as a fully cyborg.

As you remember when Naruto, Sasuke, and Hinata fighting to the most powerful Otsutsuki, the frog that Naruto expected to came out was not the frog he called, but the son of the frog, and Naruto asked the frog where his father was, why he was the one to get one and not his father. He told Naruto that his father was not around because he was busy.

See? It can be Jiraiya. He knows Naruto well, he thought that Naruto was the one who killed the powerful Otsusuki. Due to the karma seal was found in Boruto, Kashin knows how karma seal can get. When they killed one of the powerful Otsusuki.